# Google Recaptcha not shown for automation test in headless chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, jenkins, protractor, recaptcha

I have an Angular page which makes use of `google recaptcha`. I have written the automation test using `Protractor` for the same(And have used testing site/secret key for recaptcha) and it works fine for chrome browser.

But I have a requirement to use `Xvfb` to run `virtualized Chrome` as part of the testing process in `ubuntu/jenkins`. And I have the Chrome drivers installed. When I run the test with this setup and following capability setting for protractor,

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',

  chromeOptions: {
     args: [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1800,1800" ]
   }
  }
```

The Captcha just doesn't show up and it displays as below,
[image]

Chrome driver version is `chromedriver_2.31`

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue, attempting to get a screenshot with a reCaptcha in the page. The technologies were different but the underlying use of google-chrome headless is the same (am using Puppeteer). The fix is to set the userAgent to something compatible, like the browser you regularly use.
In my case (with puppeteer):

```
await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/60.0.3112.113 Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36')
```

For some other agent strings: see [Chrome userAgents](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent).

For Protractor, you can set the user agent like so:

```
    capabilities: {
'browserName': 'chrome',
'chrome-switches' : ["--user-agent ='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/60.0.3112.113 Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36'"]
},
```

Hope that works for you.

Comment: I think this is not working anymore. Any update on this?

Comment: The puppeteer use I cite here still works for me at the version I am using. There have been no breaking changes as far as I can tell in the google-chrome headless. The Protractor implementation (shown in answer) might have changed, but I did not find info to that regard.